# reassemble pcap traces to recover HTTP level data

Tags: python, http, pcap, tcpdump

I have tcpdump traces from which I want to recover reassemble HTTP requests and responses. Is there a good tool to do that. Python preferred but willing to write a wrapper if python solution not available.

Comment: if there's only a few then you can open the dump in wireshark (then right click on a message and select something like "follow conversation" - can't remember exact term)

Comment: Thanks but they are not few. I need a scriptable way to do things because I need to further process the conversations from many traces.

Comment: ok.  if you don't find any other solution, it it possible to script wireshark with lua.  but i have no idea what exactly is involved or whether it would be worthwhile in this case.

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting. It may not work for the current project but will be worth looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) performs robust TCP stream reassembly and parses a variety of application-layer protocols in a port-independent fashion. That is, if your trace contains HTTP traffic on any non-standard HTTP ports, Bro detects it.

Bro's HTTP analyzer does exactly what you need out of the box: it takes the TCP stream and deconstructs it into HTTP headers and bodies, for both requests and responses. Simply run Bro and look at the `http.log`:

```
bro -r trace.pcap
less http.log
```

Bro also comes with Python bindings, meaning, you can send all HTTP events to your custom Python script for individual processing.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/).

To appeal to your python sensibilities, you might also want to look at [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Comment: I do not think tcpreplay has any application layer protocol knowledge. Correct me if I am wrong. Scapy makes things simpler but does not still does not have knowledge of the protocol - like what kind of request it is or what are the headers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
##this_script.bro##
@load-sigs /usr/local/bro/share/bro/policy/frameworks/signatures/detect-payload.sig 
global x: string = "";

redef tcp_content_delivery_ports_orig += {[80/tcp] = T};
event tcp_contents(c: connection, is_orig: bool, seq: count, contents: string)
{
x += contents;
}

event signature_match(state:signature_state, msg:string, data:string)
{
print fmt(msg);
print data;  
}

event bro_done()
{
print x;    #reassemble payload
}
```

This is a script that displays the tcp stream reassembled payloads on port 80. You can run by bro -i iface_name this_script.bro. This helps you in analyzing the request made